# Bootstrap accordion menus

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, accordion

I am implementing Bootstrap accordions to provide additional information. However, when I click on one of them, they all open. Is there something I can add whether it be in HTML, CSS, or JS to prevent them from all opening and closing at once? It may seem like there is alot of CSS jumbo, but its for hiding highlights and glow and a bunch of other things because I just want the base accordion structure. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE** I fixed the first issue I was having, but not when I reload the page everything is collapsed like I want, but the arrows are blue and pointing up and showing that it is open. However, if I click on it twice, then it correctly shows the collapsed arrow.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-12 offset-4 my-5" id="dropdowns">
            <h4 id="data" class="ph">Test accordions</h2>
            <div class="accordion">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button style="font-weight: bold; background-color: #f5f5f5;"class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Test
                    </button>
                    <div id="collapseOne"class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body" style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
                            Placeholder text
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button style="font-weight: bold; background-color: #f5f5f5;"class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Test
                    </button>
                    <div id="collapseOne"class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body" style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
                            Placeholder text
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button style="font-weight: bold; background-color: #f5f5f5;"class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Test
                    </button>
                    <div id="collapseOne"class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body" style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
                            Placeholder text
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button style="font-weight: bold; background-color: #f5f5f5;"class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Test
                    </button>
                    <div id="collapseOne"class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body" style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
                            Placeholder text
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button style="font-weight: bold; background-color: #f5f5f5;"class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Test
                    </button>
                    <div id="collapseOne"class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body" style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
                            Placeholder text
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


.ph {

        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .accordion-button:focus {
        font-weight: bold;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-color: black;
    }
    
    .accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
        color: black;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
      }
      
    .accordion-button:link, .accordion-button:visited, .accordion-button:hover, .accordion-button:active {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: hidden;
        border-color: #f5f5f5;
        box-shadow: 0px;
    }
      
    /* .accordion-button:focus {
        z-index: 3;
        border-color: #f5f5f5;
        outline: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem #f5f5f5;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    } */
    
    .accordion-item {
        border-top: hidden;
        border-left: hidden;
        border-right: hidden;
        border-bottom-color: #d4d4d4;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-bottom-width: 2px;
        /* width: 100%; */
        /* padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px; */
    
    }
    
    .accordion-button {
        /* position: absolute;
        left: 0px; */
        padding-left: 0px;
    
    }
```

Comment: It seems they share `id`. Of course if you actually paste the code it would help

Comment: Yeah sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your `accordion-item` divs have the same `aria-labelledby="headingOne"` so its opening any accordion that has the label headingOne, go through each and give them unique label like `aria-labelledby="headingTwo"` then `aria-labelledby="headingThree"` and you should be good to go

Comment: I just tried that and it is still closing and opening all at once

Comment: try also updating the `data-bs-target="#collapseOne"` to be specific to the number of the accordion as well as the `aria-controls="collapseOne"` sorry I didn't look closely enough before but these all should be specific to the number of the accordion that your trying to target, you can also compare your code to the bootstrap documentation if this doesn't work https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/

Comment: that worked thank you. I also had to change the id for each one

Comment: now though when I reload the page, all of the little arrows are facing up and blue which is what they show when they are open

Comment: The blue arrow is dictated by the class `collapsed` which should be appended beside the `accordion-button` class when the accordion is closed

Comment: Perfect that fixed it all. Thank you so much. I was trying collapse instead of collapsed.